# Error when trying to install Xdebug on Red Hat server

Tags: php, installation, configuration, xdebug

I wanted to install Xdebug on a Red Hat server. I followed the instructions on appeared on the xdebug.org/wizard but when reached the stage of entering this line:

```
./configure --with-php-config= /www/server/php/72/etc/php.ini
```

it displayed this error after several lines:

```
checking build system type... Invalid configuration '/www/server/php/72/bin/php-config': machine '/www/server/php/72/bin/php' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/sh ./config.sub /www/server/php/72/bin/php-config failed
```

Could you please help solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It was solved I just entered this and it was solved:

./configure --with-php-config=/www/server/php/72/bin/php-config

I installed php-devel by "yum install php-devel" also but I don't think this was a part of the solution because I had installed it before.
I think the problem was the " " before the PATH and that the path was wrong